# WSO2 APIM. Policies. List of white IP addresses

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Шn additional policies, you can add one IP address or range. but how to check list of IP addresses?

I  tried to add multiple conditional groups to one policy. ( https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/access-control/ )

```
Case 1. Works
policy name = projectName
Conditional Group 1 : ip = 10.10.0.12

Case 2. Not Works
policy name = projectName
Conditional Group 1 : ip = 10.10.0.12
Conditional Group 2 : ip = 93.10.0.12
```

p.s. If add Conditional groups with different IP addresses, - that works how "AND" (not how OR) - verified

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add IP addresses for an `Advance Rate Limiting Policy`, have you tried to add multiple conditional groups? You can add more than one per policy.

Comment: Thank's for answer

Yes, I  tried to add multiple conditional groups to one policy. ( https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/access-control/ )

Case 1. Works
policy name = projectName
Conditional Group 1 : ip = 10.10.0.12

Case 2. Not Works
policy name = projectName
Conditional Group 1 : ip = 10.10.0.12
Conditional Group 2 : ip = 93.10.0.12

Answer (score 0):

works with these combinations of parameters
[image]

[image]

[image]